# how to post two id in insert function in phpMySQL

Tags: php

```
$user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];
$book_id=$s;
echo $s;
$date=date("y-m-d");
$description=$_POST['description'];
$price=array_sum($price1);
echo "price that goes to data base fiels".$price;
$number_of_books=$_POST['number_of_books'];
```

it is my code `$s` in `$book_id` is an array in which id are keep  but I submitted page it onle one id send to the database

Answer (score 0):

If $book_id is an array then you need to access the values my key or name for example:

```
$book_id[0];
```

Will get the first element in the array.

or if you have named values:

```
$book_id['myname'];
```

If you are unsure of the values you can print the whole array by using:

```
print_r($book_id);
```

It will show as key and value, for example:

```
0 => 'a value';
```